Покраска с помощью соседних вершин
Описание
Для начала я вам покажу эту картинку:



И так...
У меня есть основная (черная) вершина, нулевой (черный) угол и другие вершины связанные с ним.
У главной вершины есть свойство palette: Map<number, Color> который из себя представляет список связанных с ним вершин по типу [Угол вершины считая с основной линии, цвет вершины], как показано на картинке.
Мне нужно покрасить основную вершину с помощью соседних вершин вот так:



Серые линии биссектрисы.
Все углы в диапазоне [0, 2π)
Так же
Для своего же удобства я создал функцию который красит по заданным углам:
function fillSector(beginAngle: number, endAngle: number, color: Color): void;

Проблема
Я уже 3 часа не могу правильно рассчитать откуда у меня должна начаться покраска и до куда для определенного цвета, в основном из-за разреза в части с черной линией. Чуть выше этой линии у меня углы ближе к 0, а чуть ниже 2π.
Вопрос
Мне нужно узнать правильный подход к алгоритму, который будет считать сектор покраски.
Пример
Результат для примера сверху должно быть что-то вроде такого:
function aWonderfulFunction(palette: Map<number, Color>): Map<number, Color>;

const palette = new Map([
    [1 / 4 * PI, Color.RED], // От угла 1/4π приходит красный цвет
    [5 / 6 * PI, Color.GREEN], // От угла 5/6π приходит зеленый цвет
    [3 / 2 * PI, Color.BLUE], // От угла 3/2π приходит синий цвет
]);

const result = aWonderfulFunction(palette);

console.log(result);
// new Map([
//  [13 / 24 * PI, Color.RED], // От начала (0π) до биссектрисы красно-зеленого (которая под углом 13/24π) красим красным цветом
//  [14 / 12 * PI, Color.GREEN], // От биссектрисы красно-зеленого (13/24π) до биссектрисы зелено-синего (которая под углом 14/12π) красим зеленым цветом
//  [15 / 8 * PI, Color.BLUE], // От биссектрисы зелено-синего (14/12π) до биссектрисы сине-красного (которая под углом 15/8π) красим синим цветом
//  [2 * PI, Color.RED], // От биссектрисы сине-красного (14/12π) до конца (2π) красим красным цветом
// ]);


добавь [mcve]. Сейчас непонятно какой конкретно части тебе не хватает, а также в каком виде у тебя входные данные

@Grundy надеюсь получилось объяснить. Рабочий код, к сожалению, не могу показать, так как именно этот рабочий код и требуется. Могу показать только неудачные попытки решения данной задачи :)

под рабочим имелось ввиду часть, которая начальный рисунок рисует без раскраски центра. Если считать покраску не от 0π, а от первого угла - кажется все проще становится

Пока непонятна проблема: так как углы даны, достаточно сложить два соседних угла и разделить пополам, чтобы получить угол биссектрисы

@Grundy да я так и делал, но для последней части как это решить? В последней части нужно сложить первый и последний угол и разделить пополам. Но первый угол ближе к 0, а последний к 2π. Если так делать для примера сверху получу - (3/2 + 1/4) / 2 = 7/8. Получается нужно красить от 7/8π до 2π красным цветом.

перед делением просто вычти 2π

@Grundy после долгих попыток все-таки получилось. Спасибо.

Вы можете сами разместить свое решение как ответ и принять его, - оно выглядит куда как более полно, чем подсказка от MBo )

@Kromster, тут нет MBo :-D

@Kromster на самом деле как выяснилось есть некоторые случаи, где вариант сверху не работает. Правильный код выглядит вот так, но мне не хочется даже называть его правильным, ещё и оставить как ответ. Я еле с ним разобрался и оставил как есть, но не хочу вот так выложить.

Для поиска биссектрисы нужно найти на сколько один угол отличается от второго и разделить пополам и прибавить к первому.
Для углов, между которым нет перехода через угол 2π формула будет простой
(a + b) / 2

в противном случае нужна корректировка, например, добавить второму углу 2π - это позволит найти верную разницу между углами
(a + (b+2π))/2

Теперь уже результат может быть больше 2π - и этот случай так же можно скорректировать либо вычитанием 2π в случае необходимости, либо взятием остатка от деления
В js формулу можно обобщить до следующей:
var angle = ((firtsAngle + secondAngle + (firtsAngle > secondAngle)*2*Math.PI)/2) % (2*Math.PI)


Просто знаете в чем была главная проблема? Если угол не выходит за границы значит он должен быть добавлен спереди, а цвет должен быть цвет первого элемента. В противном случае он должен быть добавлен в Map в конце уже с цветом последнего элемента. Так же надо не забывать, что в таком случае последняя покараска должна начаться оттуда. Подробнее...

@eccs0103, тут детали реализации, без рабочего примера непонятно как это в итоге работает :)

Я могу показать рабочий проект, но он огромный. Не думаю что смогу вырезать конкретно эту часть.

@eccs0103, поэтому пример должен быть минимальным :):):)

Есть ещё такой способ, который не боится переходов через 0
(не подходит напрямую, если разность углов >=Pi):
csum = cos(a)+cos(b)
ssum = sin(a)+sin(b)
middle = atan2(ssum, csum)

По сути - складываются единичные направляющие вектора углов, определяется направление суммарного вектора.

Поскольку у меня углы в диапазоне [0, 2π), у меня оба варианта работают.

Пожалуйста, добавьте упоминание на мой комментарий или хотя бы ссылку, чтобы приходящий сюда, увидев ваш принятый ответ понял как и откуда начать. Ну или можете ставить полное решение у себя.
